# Implementation of non increasing list with STL C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

In a problem inputs are several lists of numbers,

Ex-

```
(1,5,4,3), (2,7,3,1,5), (1,9,1,7,3,7,2), (3,5,4,2,3).
```

where each list may appear twice.

In the final output distinct lists should be printed, in which elements in each list should be sorted in non increasing order, as well as lists should be sorted like that.

Is it possible to implement this whole thing with map in c++ ?

Output for the above example should be

```
9,7,7,3,2,1,1

7,5,3,2,1

5,4,3,3,2

5,4,3,1
```

Simply,set of unique lists where within each lists numbers again sorted in non increasing order.

Comment: What do you mean by "where each list may appear twice"?  Would you provide an example of that?

Comment: That means say list ( 1,5,4,3 ),(2,5,1) again (1,5,4,3)..... are inputs.

Comment: so in that case the output should be (5,4,3,1) (5,4,3,1) (5,2,1) ?

Comment: no "In the final output distinct lists should be printed" mentioned there.So only (5,4,3,1) (5,2,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set`  will definitely help you.  You will get a unique sorted list as the resultant set if you insert your list into a `std::set<int>`

**Edit:**

```
std::set<std::multiset<int, std::greater<int>> myList;
```

Inner set going to sort in non increasing order and keeping duplicates elements, and outer set going to keep only unique list of inner list.

Comment: Not exactly , I actually want to implement a set of unique lists where within each lists numbers again sorted in non increasing order.

Comment: +1 That's how I would do it... here's a demo in Coliru Viewer http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56fe2e6be9358404